# How to get and pass json from model to controller?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get json data from database (sql) with node.js and then pass it to app.get (express.js) but without success.

I have two files urls.js which should get all urls from database and in app.js I'm trying to create api endpoint with express.js. I have managed to get json data in app.js if I write query there and run it but I do not know how to separate it into two files.

code that works in app.js

```
app.get('/api/urls', (request, response) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM urls', (error, result) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    response.send(result);
  });
});
```

I've tried to separate it into two files so in urls.js (model like) I could have something like

```
class Urls {
  async getUrls() {
    const sql = `select * from urls`;
    return await db.query(sql); 
  }
}

module.exports = Urls;
```

and then call it in app.js (controller like):

```
const data = new Urls();
app.get(/api/urls, (req, res) => {
  res.send(data.getUrls());
}
```

In both cases result should be json

Comment: What 'sql' library are you using? Does `console.log(result)` display your data? Though, you should use `response.json(result)` to send your data.

Comment: it is mysql essentially.  Cconsole.log(result) gives me json, And it is fine. but that second example, when i add:

const x =  await db.query(sql);
const y = await JSON.stringify(x) 
console.log(y);

it prints json to console but I don't know how to pass it to app.get?

Comment: So basically I need to pass data from model (urls.js) to controller (app.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getUrls function is async it will return promise,so do something like this

```
const data = new Urls();
app.get(/api/urls, (req, res) => {
data.getUrls().then(response=>{
res.send(response);

})

}
```